# How to find which app is using my keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-keypad

i am going to develop an keyboard for android. whether i can able to get the package name of an app which is using my keyboard in android.

is this possible to package or app name from my keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rely on getCurrentInputEditorInfo(), a method in InputMethodService, to achieve this:

```
String packageName = getCurrentInputEditorInfo().packageName;
```